# Show that if $\langle x_0\rangle$ is a $n$-cycle and $n$ is a prime number, then $\langle x_0\rangle$ is a prime $n$-cycle.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

Show that if $\langle x_0\rangle$ is a $n$-cycle and $n$ is a prime number, then $\langle x_0\rangle$ is a prime $n$-cycle.

Recall: a natural number $n\neq 1$ is a prime number if there are no proper divisors of $n$; the latter means if $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\frac{n}{m}$, then $m=1$ or $m=n$.

(Hint: given that $\langle x_0\rangle$ is a $n$-cycle, let $m$ be the first natural number larger than $1$ with $x_m=x_0$. Show that $m$ divides $n$).

---

I know to be a $n$-cycle it must satisfy $\langle x_0\rangle = ${$x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1}$} with $x_0=F(x_{n-1})$

and to be a prime $n$-cycle it must also satisfy $x_i \neq x_0$ for $i=1,2,...,n-1$

How does one prove the above statements with that knowledge?

Comment: What does $k$ have to do with anything in the definition of a prime $n$-cycle?

Comment: The condition $x_i\ne x_0$ for $i=1,2,...,n-1$ implies that the smallest number $m$ with $x_m=x_0$ is $m=n$. And this implies that there is no cycle with length less than $n$.

Comment: I guess such a cycle has the property that $x_{i+1} = F(x_i)$ for some $F$ so if $x_m = x_0$ then $x_{i+m} = x_i$ and because $x_p = x_0$ with $p$ prime then $m | p$ so $x_1=x_0$ or $(x_0,\ldots,x_{p-1})$ is a prime $p$-cycle